# AngularJS $timeout in for loop generates wrong values

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I add some items in the `for` loop with `$timeout` to see the animation. It works, but I see wrong values in the `<li>` items:

```
$scope.list = [{ id : 1},{ id : 2},{ id : 3},{ id : 4},{ id : 5},{ id : 6}];

for (var i = 0; i < $scope.myItems.length; i++) {
   var x = $scope.myItems[i];

   $log.log(x.id);

   $timeout(function () {
      $scope.list.push({ name: x.id });
   }, 100 * i);
};

<ul class="item-container">
  <li class="item" ng-class="animation" ng-repeat="item in list">{{item.name}}</li>
</ul>
```

firebug displays:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
```

but in the `<ul>` tag all `<li>` items have `6` as a value. Why ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since timeout is on a delay, you'll have to wrap it in a closure so that the "x" is the right one:

```
for (var i = 0; i < $scope.myItems.length; i++) {
   var x = $scope.myItems[i];
   (function(x){

       $log.log(x.id);

       $timeout(function () {
          $scope.list.push({ name: x.id });
       }, 100 * i);
   })(x);
};
```

This is because the x continously gets overwriten via x = $scope.myItems[i]. By the time the timeout fires the x has changed to the last one.